# How to add resultset to csv file in camel

Tags: apache-camel, marshalling, camel-sql

My xml is given below

```
 <camelContext trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <propertyPlaceholder id="placeholder" location="classpath:application.properties" />

    <!--Route:1 for POLLUX Data Processing   -->

 <route id="processPolluxData-Route" startupOrder="1">
<from uri="{{POLLUX_INPUT_PATH}}?noop=true"/>
  <unmarshal ref="csvBindyDataformatForPolluxData"/>
  <camel:bean ref="polluxDataController" method="processPolluxData"/>
  <camel:log message="Line:${body}" loggingLevel="INFO"/> 
<to uri="sqlComponent:{{sql.insertPolluxData}}?batch=true"  /> 
</route> 

     <!-- Route:2 for RSI Data Processing -->

<route id="processRsiData-Route" startupOrder="2">
<from uri="{{RSI_INPUT_PATH}}?noop=true"/>
  <unmarshal ref="csvBindyDataformatForRsiData"/>
  <camel:bean ref="rsiDataController" method="processRsiData"/>
  <camel:log message="Line:${body}" loggingLevel="INFO"/> 
<to uri="sqlComponent:{{sql.insertRsiData}}?batch=true" /> 
</route>

    <!-- Route for Global Data Processing  -->
    <route id="processGlobalData-Route"  >
    <from uri="sqlComponent:{{sql.selectOrder}}?consumer.useIterator=false" />
         <camel:bean ref="globalDataController" method="processGlobalData" />  
        <marshal>
            <csv delimiter=","/>
        </marshal>
        <log message="${body}" />
    <setHeader headerName="camelFilename">
        <constant>result.csv</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="{{GLOBAL_OUTPUT_PATH}}?fileExist=Append" />
</route>
```

My sql statement is

```
sql.selectOrder=select STID,CLLTR,SOURCE from GSI_DEVL.POLLUX_DATA
```

bean class for processing result set is

```
public class GlobalDataController {

List<Map<String, Object>> globalStationProccessedList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
List<Map<String, Object>> globalStationMap = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Map<String, Object>> processGlobalData(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    // System.out.println("Processing " + exchange.getIn().getBody());

    globalStationMap = (List<Map<String, Object>>) exchange.getIn().getBody();
    globalStationProccessedList.addAll(globalStationMap);

    return globalStationProccessedList;
}
```

}

Problem now is Route 1 data is transffered to csv file with exact number of rows in database.But no data in the route 2 is append to the csv file
I am using camel 2.16

Answer (score 0):

If the problem only in large number of files (not in the file format), then here is the solution:

```
  <route id="processOrder-route">
    <from uri="sqlComponent:{{sql.selectOrder}}"/>
    <camel:bean ref="controllerformarshalling" method="processGlobalData"  />
    <marshal >
    <csv delimiter="," useMaps="true" > </csv>
     </marshal>
    <log message="${body}"/>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
        <constant>result.csv</constant>
    </setHeader>  
    <to uri="file://D://cameltest//output&amp;fileExist=Append" />
  </route>
```

For next pool you can set another file name, based on current time, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting this parameter on the sql component?

> consumer.useIterator boolean true
>      Camel 2.11: SQL consumer only: If true each row returned when
>   polling will be processed individually. If false the entire
>   java.util.List of data is set as the IN body.

Try setting this to false. That way you should get the entire sql resultset into a single list and then write the entire list to a single file.

Comment: Your solution worked !! Thanks

But the result set contains 34000 rows in database, in the file i am getting only 2000 rows.Is there is any limitation ?
please help

Comment: Seems strange, as I don't think there is any default limitation. In camel, what is the value for the exchange header CamelSqlRowCount after getting the resultset? Is it 2000 or 34000?

Comment: Which version of Camel are you using?

Comment: You can also try setting maxMessagesPerPoll=100000 just to see that all 34000 rows are indeed written if you do get 34000 rows back in the Camel resultset.

Comment: Souciance,
I have edited the question with code ? The issue is with one route i think.Can you please read the edited part and help me ?

Comment: Sure, if the answer is correct, perhaps you can mark as well? That would be appreciated.

Comment: By the way, did you check the Camel header and saw that the resultset in Camel did indeed return 34000 and not 2000?

Comment: how can i see the header values for count,which code i used to do that ? can you explain ?

Comment: You can find it here: http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html You can use a simple statement like simple("${headers.CamelSqlRowCount}") or similar after you have fetched the data. Either set the body to this statement or create a log statement.